# Ruby Multi-Process Synchronization

Tags: ruby, process, synchronization

I have a piece of ruby code which processes multiple files . It's works roughly like this,

```
1)check the 'done' json file to ignore files which have already been processed.
2)Pick up a file from remaining files to process
3)process the file
4)write a entry in 'done' file
5)repeat
```

i am trying to make it run in a multi process environment, the goal is to run the ruby file multiple times in different shells.

First problem i encountered was at part 1. There is a race condition there when multiple processes are trying to get the next file to process.Aka when the entry is not in the 'done' file , then multiple processes can pick up the same file to process.(to this end i introduced a .lock file)

Also a process needs to know which file is currently being processed by another process so to ignore it too.(for this i introduced a 'concurrent file')

Now my algorithm looks likes this,

```
1)wait for the .lock file to be not there
2)create the .lock file
3)read and ignore the files listed in the 'done' file
4)read and ignore the files listed in the 'concurrent' file
5)choose a file to process
6)write a entry in the 'concurrent' file
7)delete the .lock file
8)process the file
9)remove the entry from 'concurrent' file
10)add a entry in 'done' file
11)repeat
```

Now it seemed to work  , until i started creating more than 5 processes.

After bit of debugging i found that multiple processes are creating the .lock file at the same time.

here is my sychronization code,

```rb
def wait_for_key
  loop do
    if File.exists? "#{file_path}/.lock"
      puts "waiting for lock to be released"
      sleep 1
    else
      break
    end
  end
end

def lock
  FileUtils.touch "#{file_path}/.lock"
  puts "download method locked #{Time.now}"
end

def release_lock
  FileUtils.rm "#{file_path}/.lock"
  puts "lock released #{Time.now}"
  sleep 1
end
```

so the concurrent algo runs roughly like this,

```
wait_for_key
lock
.....do some stuff 
release_lock
```

So if multiple processes are hitting the lock method at the same time, it seems there is a race condition in wait_for_key method.That is multiple processes see that the .lock file is not present than they call the lock method at the same time.

I don't know really where to go from here, i looked into ruby mutex but it looks like it only works for multiple threads.

Any ideas will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can determine which files need to be processed **before** you spawn child processes.
2. If you have access to a Redis server, then put those filenames into a Redis list, and then spawn child processes and let them pop one filename at a time and process it, until the list gets empty. If you don't have access to Redis, then you can evenly assign the files to the child processes. In neither case do you need a global lock or a mutex.

Comment: am not forking child processes for now , am running the same script in multiple shells.Also i forgot to add , those files am processing are not constant and not under my control. So every time i check for files to process there maybe more files than the last time.

Comment: If you use the Redis approach, it's the same thing. If you want to distribute the files evenly, without Redis, then just make multiple manifest files, each containing a portion of the filenames of the files to be processed, and let each "worker process" read a unique manifest file.

Comment: The reason am not forking is not to garble log messages , though i may start forking once the code gets stable. But how do you propose determining the file that needs to be processed from the parent process, am not sure i got that

Comment: In that case, each "worker process" may push filenames to another Redis list (let's call it the "done list") when a file processing is done. When the "controller process" starts up, it first works out a diff of the current files and the previous "done list".

Comment: If you want to do file processing on the fly when files are continuously added, then you may want an MQ.

Comment: i simplified the scenario while describing my situation , there are also other constraints involved, like i have a 2 separate list of files , list1 and list2 from which to process. I have to process list1 first. It can hold the max 6 files. Then i have to move files from list2 to list1 to process. List1 and list2 can have additional files in the next run ..things like that.  I think what your suggesting is to have a script collect all the file names and add it to redis and then another script(multiple) to pop file  names from redis and process them ....

Comment: i dunno am still thinking , it may not work with the constraints i have , also there has to be a good ol' ruby way to do this , i mean redis is synchronizing it some way too...

Comment: Well, if you insist using only Ruby, then you can make a controlling process that accesses the manifest file (or "done" file) and make sure no other process can access that file. The "worker processes" only **ask** the controlling process for what file should be processed next. You may need a `Queue` to queue up the requests from the worker processes.

Comment: sorry what i meant was that the constraints are such that the decision of which  file to process can only be made at runtime. I cannot keep the information of what files to process separate from processing. Only once i have locked the file for processing can i be certain that i can process it. And there are only few files i can lock at a time.

Comment: what i want is a global lock while a process is running the algo to pick up the file to process and then lock it for processing. Other processes should not be allowed to run that code while one process is going thru it so that same file is not locked by multiple processes

Comment: Have a look at `File#flock`.

Comment: awesome Aetherus, this is exactly what i was looking for ! tested with 10 concurrent processes and didn't see any race conditions yet.... So instead of creating and deleting .lock file to synchronize access to code am using File#flock instead now.

Comment: thanks very much for your time and help , much appreciated :) . Also do you wanna put this as a answer so i accept that as the correct answer ?